# How to create a new rails 3 app that uses jQuery as a js framework

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

1. How to create a new rails 3 app that uses jQuery as a js framework?
2. How to switch an existing rails 3 app to use jQuery in the "rails" way?

Any guides, please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the gem to your Gemfile and follow instructions from here:

https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails

FYI: jQuery will be the default js framework in Rails 3.1

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a new rails 3 app with http://railswizard.org/ (and include jquery as the default js framework) to speed up your setup process

Comment: you're right, that worth noticing, +1 :)